Why can't filesystems provide direct access to the physical sector allocations (extents/groups) of a file?
I'm working on a database project where I need to write to both a data.bin file (for storing data) and a metadata file. I'm running into an issue with the overhead caused by filesystem metadata updates, especially when using undo logs. Every write operation essentially doubles, leading to 8x writes for a single data update (2 writes for data and meta multiplied by 2 writes for undo logs, multiplied by 2 due to filesystem).
To reduce this overhead, I'm considering bypassing the filesystem for metadata management and directly managing sector writes myself. My idea is to:
Preallocate a large block of sectors for the data.bin file.
Maintain a pointer in my metadata file, which I would advance (like fseek) each time I allocate a new sector.
The challenge I'm facing is that I can't find a reliable way to get all the extensions (start addresses, sectors forming the file) that the filesystem allocates to my data.bin file. Without this information, I can't properly manage the sectors directly and avoid filesystem metadata updates every time I allocate a new sector.
Is there a way to retrieve the specific sector addresses or clusters that a file occupies on disk? Or, is there a better approach to achieve what I'm trying to do, which is to minimize the number of writes required for data and metadata updates by bypassing the filesystem’s metadata management?
Total Writes with Undo file system updates and undo logs:
Undo Log Writes (2x): Writing original data and metadata to the undo log.
Data and Metadata Writes (2x): Performing the actual data write and updating the filesystem metadata.
Filesystem Writes (2x): Updating the filesystem with the new undo log entries and final metadata and data.
Thus, you have:
2 Writes: Undo log (original data + metadata).
2 Writes: Actual data and metadata updates.
2 Writes: Updating the filesystem with the undo log entries.
2 Writes: Updating the filesystem with the final metadata.
I'd like to eliminate the filesystem metadata update at each write since I want to provide my own metadata for my db anyway and use the drivers that my MCU provides to drive directly to my SD card sectors.
I use FatFs.

You can try writing to a raw partition without a filesystem, i.e. /dev/sda2.

Yes that's a good idea, and I did think about that, but the problem is that if I want to insert my sd card in a computer and copy paste the db file, its impossible when the db wasn't handled by a filesystem

You can still do that: dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=/tmp/data.bin bs=1M count=100 for a 100MB partition.

Are you able to use mmap() and msync(), and let the OS schedule writes?

Note that  this is an operating system issue. Some OSes (Windows for example) can in fact tell you the disk extents, at least for some file systems.

You could try modifying FatFs to check whether the directory entry is actually being changed (i.e. new contents differ from old contents), and skip writing it back if it hasn't changed. It should only change if the file size increases or if the timestamp changes. If using a real timestamp (rather than a dummy, fixed timestamp), it should only change every two seconds. You can minimize file size changes by increasing the size in large increments rather than small increments.

What is the storage media? What is the filesysyem? What is the OS? Why is this tagged "embedded"? - Understanding that may lead to a more appropriate answer.

From a program point of view, a file (like a raw device) is just a sequence of bytes. It doesn't matter if these bytes were allocated at once (one "extension") or at different times (multiple "extensions"). You just fseek() looking for a given byte.
Let's say you preallocate 1 MB (rounded to the cluster granularity). That's just one metadata operation. Then you write inside the file, advancing your "last byte" (or "last block") pointer (which is saved apart, in your own metadata).
When you go pass the current file size (1 MB), you just allocate (pre-write) another 1 MB (that's a second metadata operation), and fseek() linearly to the next byte in the whole file.
Byte 1024*1024 would be the first byte in the second "extension", but you don't really need to care about the extension number and the relative position inside it. You don't need to think about volume logical sectors, or about physical sectors, cylinders and heads.
This is exactly what database servers, like Oracle or SQL Server, do with datafiles: they preallocate a file, fill it, then extend it when it's needed. (Of course, the "extensions" don't need to be equally sized.)
Actually, database servers may also add new (data)files, which act as extensions of the first one. That's just a little bit more complicated.
(Yes, inside each datafile there are several segments (one for each table, index, partition , etc), and each segment has one or more extents, which may be in separate non-contiguous "areas" of the datafile; just like each file of a filesystem has one or more clusters, which may be in separate non-contiguous blocks of the disk partition or logical volume. Some kind of tracking is needed for handling this, but it has nothing to do with your problem.)
You are specially concerned by undo logs. Database servers usually don't extend log files. They preallocate the required space (ie. they create one or more logfiles of a fixed size) and use this space in a circular way (just like a circular buffer in memory, but in disk). This means that undo log blocks (or "records") have a limited lifetime. Usually, they are overwritten when the associated data has already been written to the datafile(s). (Edit: moved this text from the comments sections.)
We're assuming the filesystem metadata is only written when the file is extended (ie. when we allocate a new set of blocks). But some filesystems also update the metadata (the "last modified date") each time the file is actually written, or maybe when it's closed (after one or more write operations).
You should check how this works on your specific OS. Also, if you're on Unix, some filesystems have mount options (in fstab, etc) for controlling which kind of metadata is written, and when. This may also be controlled by some options in the open() call.

Actually I use fatfs so there's still write amplification, gpt:
FATF still needs to update certain meta after each write:
File Size: If the write operation changes the file size, the filesystem will update the size in the directory entry.
Last Modified Time: FATFS will update the file's timestamps to reflect the most recent modification.

According to this, your solution (but seeking for a given byte inside the whole file, as I suggested, forgetting about physical positioning) will work. The only problematic point I see is in the line "may update the file's timestamps". But note it says "MAY update" (and, anyway, this operation is always differed, not immediate, which greatly reduces its impact).

I've seen a post on an electronic forum that said will but yes, gpt said may

Don't trust gpt. If you ask again, he'll apologize and give you a different answer. Read the documentation of the software. Which fs did you say? FatFs for embedded systems, over Microsoft FAT/FAT32? Read (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times). And please remember: this strategy actually works for high performant database servers.

thanks, that was a good idea "Also, if you're on Unix, some filesystems have mount options (in fstab, etc) for controlling which kind of metadata is written, and when. This may also be controlled by some options in the open() call."
But I'm done checking the doc more than twice and it doesn't have such option since the library is just a simple library made to be lightweight. I presuppose that it would always update the meta with the timestamp by default because of its 'simple design for simple use case with microcontrollers'.

I've just read the official FatFs documentation and I couldn't find a clear statement, but I'm pretty sure it'll delay the update of the "modified date" until the close (or, in the worst case and according to Microsoft directives, no less than 2 seconds between two updates). You may also want to check the FF_ options available in ffconf.h.
